# How do I find the foreign key of a table using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I can get the columns of a table in sql server using this query:

```
  select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'MyTable'
```

but **How do I find the foreign key columns** associated with that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inside `information_schema.table_constraints`.

EDIT:

Wait, I think `information_schema.key_column_usage` is better:

```
select * from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_name = '...'
```

And then if you need to make sure that it is really a foreign key, query table_constraints using the constraint name that you got from above:

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_name = '...'
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but how do I determine which columns are Relation with each column.

Comment: Should be `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` etc, so the queries work on a case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all the FK constraints on a given table.  Just set `'table_name'` to your tables name.  The query is below:

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(100);
SET @TABLENAME='table_name';

SELECT
    K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
    FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
    Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                i1.TABLE_NAME,
                i2.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE
                i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME

    WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME=@TABLENAME
```